# Serving a modified asset-manifest.json in CRA using CRACO doesn't work

Tags: create-react-app, webpack-dev-server, craco

I have just created a new CRA app. In our organization we have a micro frontend framework which has certain requirements when it comes to the the asset file of each micro frontend app. CRA will by default, create a asset-manifest.json file.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L656

Now I need to change this file to assets.json and make some structural changes as well. To achieve this I use CRACO and add the WebpackManifestPlugin.

```
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        plugins: {
            // tried removing CRA definition for ManifestPlugin. 
            // It worked, but had no impact on my problem 
            // remove: ['ManifestPlugin'],
            add: [
            new ManifestPlugin({
                fileName: 'assets.json',
                generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
                    const js = [],
                        css = [];
                    files.forEach((file) => {
                        if (file.path.endsWith('.js') && file.isInitial) {
                            js.push({ value: file.path, type: 'entry' });
                        }
                        if (file.path.endsWith('.css') && file.isInitial) {
                            css.push({ value: file.path, type: 'entry' });
                        }
                    });
                    return { js, css };
                },
            })
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Whenever I build the application, my new assets.json file is generated as expected.

However, I can't get CRA, or webpack-dev-server I assume, to serve this file while I run my CRA app in development mode. It only resolves to the index.html file. I have looked through CRA source code and can't really find any relevant place where asset-manifest.json is mentioned.

So how do I get webpack-dev-server to serve my assets.json file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ManifestPlugin` to `webpack.plugins.remove` array to receive only the configuration from `WebpackManifestPlugin`:

```js
...
   webpack: {
        alias: {},
        plugins: {
            add: [
                new WebpackManifestPlugin(webpackManifestConfig)
            ],
            remove: [
                "ManifestPlugin"
            ],
        },
        configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => { return webpackConfig; }
    },
...
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but `remove` needs to be `remove: [ 'WebpackManifestPlugin' ]`